# How to check if email exists in two tables using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to export newsletter subscribers from my website.

Using the platforms own export facility, it doesn't export the first name and last name of the subscriber in the same file as the email addresses of the subscribers.

I do have access to the db via phpmyadmin.

In phpmyadmin, I can export the users (90k) in one run, and export the subscribers (18k) in one run, but I don't know how to match them up.

Is there a query I can use to get this done?

I want to search users to see if their email address exists in the subscribers field then to export that out.

The main table is called "site"

And then the fields are:

```
`site_customers`.`email`
```

and

```
`site_newslist_subscription`.`email`
```

I'm not a programmer and I don't have much experience with querying a db but if someone can help with the correct query I know enough to be able to run it in phpmyadmin.

If anyone can help with this I would be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
SELECT sc.*, sns.`email` 
FROM site_customers sc
LEFT JOIN site_newslist_subscription sns
ON sc.email = sns.email
```

(It would be much faster if `email` was indexed as that's what we're looking on)